# Expand menu item on click by data attribute which named as id

Tags: jquery, html, css, custom-data-attribute

How to expand menu item on click by data attribute which named as id? I mean, that data attribute is id (`data-cats="#movies"`).

**HTML**

```
<li class="cat" data-cats="#movies">
    MOVIES
</li>


<li class="cat" data-cats="#music">
    MUSIC
</li>


etc...


<div class="expander" id="movies">
    menu items about movies
</div>

<div class="expander" id="music">
    menu items about music
</div>

etc...
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.cat').click(function() {
    $('.expander').show();
    // dont know what to do next
});
```

**CSS**

```
.expander { display:none; }
```

If am clicking on li element, than all expanders opens, but i need to find only cliced one and expand it. Also, if am clicking on other li element, than opened one should be closed.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0jqtb91n/1/)

Thanks for any answers and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `data()` to get the value to place in the selector. Try this:

```
$('.cat').click(function() {
    $('.expander').hide(); // hide all shown divs
    $($(this).data('cats')).show(); // show the related one
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/0jqtb91n/3/)

Comment: Thank you very much. That works :). I will accept answer in 9mins :)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `#` form the IDs `<div class="expander" id="#movies">`.

```
<div class="expander" id="movies">
   menu items about movies
</div>

<div class="expander" id="music">
   menu items about music
</div>
```

---

```
$('.cat').click(function() {
        $('.expander'+$(this).data('cats')).show(); //or just $($(this).data('cats')).show();
});
```